# Oracle - SQL Plus | Windows | Pipes - Different results for same command on different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus, pipe

I am trying to reset temporary tables via a simple commandline script and am using the following command:

```
@echo DELETE FROM A ; | sqlplus schema/pass@DSN
```

This works for table A.
For a similar table B, the statement is not executed. The commandline logs into the database and displays the SQL> shell. It does not react to keystrokes and does nothing. I have to exit the commandline interface.

I tried different ordering of the commands in the batch file and executed the statement from commandline directly. Same error.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just taking a long time to perform the delete? How many rows are affected, from both tables? If there aren't many, is something else (another session's delete or update) locking a row being deleted, which would wait indefinitely? The `SQL>` prompt is shown either way - it doesn't mean it's doing nothing...

Comment: The row count is around 400 rows with 9 columns. I can try keeping it running for a longer while. But I already had the window open for around 4 minutes.

Comment: Then something else is probably locking it. Do you have an uncommitted delete or update against that table in any other open sessions? In a Toad or SQL Developer window, for example? If you've tested the delete somewhere, roll back in that session and see if the batch version magically finishes.

Comment: Worked. I should have tried that before posting. Now I feel retarted. Thanks. (How do I vote on the comment?)

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered in a comment. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Alex Poole wrote:

> Do you have an uncommitted delete or update against that table in any other open sessions? In a Toad or SQL Developer window, for example? If you've tested the delete somewhere, roll back in that session and see if the batch version magically finishes.

The OP wrote:

> Worked. I should have tried that before posting. Now I feel retarded.
>
> SOLUTION: Uncommitted transactions in open session on table caused the error. Once transactions had been committed, the script worked fine.